# How to create an expanding sequence in R, such as c(1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5)

Tags: r, sequence

I have been trying to create the sequence c(1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5...) without using any loops. Does anyone have any idea how to create such a sequence?

Comment: How about `unlist(sapply(1:10, function(x) 1:x))`?

Comment: The could work: `row(diag(5))[upper.tri(diag(5), TRUE)]`

Comment: Perhaps you, just, want `sequence(1:5)`?

Comment: alexis_laz - UGH, was trying to remember that... knew I had seen it in one command somewhere. Make it the answer!

Comment: jbaums - if you have to unlist anyway then use the simpler and faster lapply

Answer (score 4):

I'll throw in

```
unlist(lapply(1:5, seq_len))
```

which is equivalent, if a bit longer than, alexis_jaz comment

```
sequence(1:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
do.call(c, sapply(1:5, function(x) 1:x))
```

Comment: `do.call` with `c` can be accomplished with the `unlist` function.

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
v1 <- 1:5
seq_len(sum(v1))-rep(cumsum(c(0L, v1[-length(v1)])), v1) 
#[1] 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5
```